# matplotlib heatmap text digit

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, heatmap

I would like to draw a heatmap with the following data and display the values on it.
If you draw the graph as follows, the 0.000 value will appear as 0.
I want to write 0.000 as 0.000!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[0.891, 0.111, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
                 [0.027, 0.971, 0.001, 0.000, 0.000],
                 [0.000, 0.001, 0.997, 0.001, 0.001],
                 [0.000, 0.000, 0.001, 0.997, 0.002],
                 [0.000, 0.001, 0.005, 0.028, 0.966]])

xlabels = ['label_1', 'label_2', 'label_3', 'label_4', 'label_5']
ylabels = ['label_1', 'label_2', 'label_3', 'label_4', 'label_5']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,7))

im = ax.imshow(data, cmap='Blues')

ax.set_title("Title", fontsize=16)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(5))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(5))

fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)

for i in range(len(ylabels)):
    for j in range(len(xlabels)):
        if i == j:
            text = ax.text(j, i, data[i,j], ha="center", va="center", color='w')
        else:
            text = ax.text(j, i, data[i,j], ha="center", va="center", color='black')

ax.set_axis_off()
ax.grid(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Things could be easier with seaborn: `sns.heatmap(data=data, xticklabels=xlabels, yticklabels=ylabels, square=True, cmap='Blues', annot=True, fmt='.3f',cbar=True, cbar_kws={'shrink':0.8}, ax=ax)`

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[0.891, 0.111, 0.000, 0.000, 0.000],
                 [0.027, 0.971, 0.001, 0.000, 0.000],
                 [0.000, 0.001, 0.997, 0.001, 0.001],
                 [0.000, 0.000, 0.001, 0.997, 0.002],
                 [0.000, 0.001, 0.005, 0.028, 0.966]])

xlabels = ['label_1', 'label_2', 'label_3', 'label_4', 'label_5']
ylabels = ['label_1', 'label_2', 'label_3', 'label_4', 'label_5']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,7))

im = ax.imshow(data, cmap='Blues')

ax.set_title("Title", fontsize=16)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(5))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(5))

fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)

for i in range(len(ylabels)):
    for j in range(len(xlabels)):
        if i == j:
            text = ax.text(j, i, f"{data[i,j]:.3f}", ha="center", va="center", color='w')
            #    set format here ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        else:
            text = ax.text(j, i, f"{data[i,j]:.3f}", ha="center", va="center", color='black')

ax.set_axis_off()
ax.grid(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

[image]